# What is better resizing array or copying?

Tags: c, arrays, resize

I was asked in an interview, so just out of curiosity...

Say that I have an array of {3, 6, 7, 7, 7, 1} and I want to make it {3, 6, 7, 1} removing all consecutive 7's.

Which would've been been to say? Copying the array into another array or resizing the original array? And the Pros/Cons of each

Thank you!

Btw in C or C++ please.

Comment: What array? Dynamically allocated? Auto array? In C++, is it `std::vector`?

Comment: How do you keep track of the size of the array?

Comment: What do you mean by "copy" and "resize"? These terms can mean so much - and can possibly be so wrong - without a better context: a snippet of code demonstrating the [actual] problem will go a long ways on stackoverflow. Also, FWIW, C is not C++.

Comment: Arrays can't be resized in C, so this question is non-sensical.  The only thing you can resize dynamically is a dynamically allocated block of memory.  You can have an array of unspecified size in a dynamically allocated block, and resize the block, but that's not really resizing the array.

Comment: I think that was a trick question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd resize.  Pros - fast as no copying needed.  Cons - probable memory fragmentation.  Beyond that none really as a resize downwards for something of this size would more than likely be ignored by a memory API anyway.  Anytime a downward resize occurs, the memory system does not necessarily have to move memory (but it might!).